# Exponential Random Variables and Conditional Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X \sim$ Exponential (rate = $\theta$) and $Y \sim$ Exponential (1) be independent random variables.

Define $Z \equiv \min\{X,Y\}$

I have two questions:

(1) What is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$?

(2) What is the joint distribution of $Y$ and $Z$?

Obviously these are both interrelated questions, as the answer for one probably yields the precise method to answer the other.  I have started by trying to compute the joint cdf of $X$ and $Z$ and then taking two partial derivatives:

$$F_{X,Z}(x,z) = P(X \leq x, Z \leq z) = P(X \leq x \wedge z, X \leq L) + P(X \leq x, L \leq z, L < X) \\
= \int_{0}^{x \wedge z}\int_{x_1}^\infty \theta e^{-\theta x_1} e^{-l_1}dl_1 dx_1 + \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x_1 \wedge z}\theta e^{-\theta x_1} e^{-l_1}dl_1 dx_1$$

but I am having trouble computing the integrals.  Is this the right approach?  If so, maybe there is an easier way?  If not, what is the right way?

Answer (score 2):

If $x \le z$ then
\begin{align}
P(X \le x, Z \le z)
= P(X \le x) = 1 - e^{-\theta x}.
\end{align}
If $x \ge z$ then
\begin{align}
P(X \le x, Z \le z)
&= P(X \le z, Z \le z) + P(z < X \le x, Y \le z)
\\
&= P(X \le z) + P(z < X \le x) P(Y \le z)
\\
&= (1 - e^{-\theta z}) + (e^{-\theta z} - e^{-\theta x}) (1 - e^{-z})
\end{align}

This joint distribution does not have a density with respect to Lebesgue measure because $P(X=Z) > 0$.

Comment: So what is their joint density? I'm trying to compute an MLE for $\theta$ in cases (1) and (2) but I'm confused about how to do that when I can't compute a density in the case $x \leq z$

Comment: @qp212223 If you have samples of $X$, then can't you find the MLE for $\theta$ by focusing on the distribution of $X$ alone?

Comment: I could, but I want to focus on the second case.  I see that the MLE in the first case (using the pdf provided above) is precisely the same as the regular MLE for the exponential without this minimum variable (which makes sense, it provides no extra information about $\theta$ right?)

Comment: @qp212223 I apologize, my density computation was incorrect. This joint distribution does not have a density. You may want to ask another question regarding how you perform maximum likelihood estimation on such distributions.

Comment: Ok so is the likelihood then just $$L(\theta |X, Z) = \begin{cases}1- e^{-\theta X} & X=Z \\ \theta e^{-\theta X} e^{-Z} & X > Z \end{cases}$$ and $0$ otherwise?